# Why is MtGox trying to trademark "Bitcoin"?

Tags: exchanges, economic-theory, mtgox

Someone on the #mtgox IRC channel pointed me to [this](http://esearch.oami.europa.eu/copla/trademark/data/010103646). It seems to be an application by Tibanne Co. Ltd. for the Trademark name BITCOIN.

I asked MagicalTux on #mtgox about it, but got no answer.

Why is he doing this?

Answer (score 14):

Some countries have a strict first-to-file rule. In these countries, if some malicious entity [tried to trademark the term 'Bitcoin'](http://www.techdirt.com/articles/20110707/12090715000/couple-trying-to-trademark-bitcoin-via-dubious-claims.shtml) it could cause problems for others trying to use it to talk about the currency. Tibanne is trying to protect the community from this kind of nonsense. [Source.](https://mtgox.com/press_release_20111014.html)

Comment: This is confirmed by the statement they have since made - https://mtgox.com/press_release_20111014.html

Comment: oh yeah. And you believe that?
Who says they don't leverage this trademark in the future.