#  What are the dangers of MtGox's trademark over Bitcoin?

Tags: legal, mtgox

If anyone trademarks bitcoin, shouldn't it be Satoshi, Gavin or one of the people who actually made it instead of some exchange site that's trying to profit from it and faces competition from other exchanges?

I mean, if Mt.Gox wanted, wouldn't they be able to shut down Tradehill or at least charge royalties if they were able to enforce their trademark? A very dangerous prospect.

Comment: It might be helpful if you actually linked to the background of exactly what you're talking about. Also your question lacks specifics and sounds a bit more like FUD than an actual inquiry.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/1031/why-is-mtgox-trying-to-trademark-bitcoin

Answer (score 3):

> If anyone trademarks bitcoin, shouldn't it be Satoshi, Gavin or one of the people who actually made it[.]

You'd have to take that up with them. Thus far, they haven't.

> I mean, if GOX wanted, wouldn't they be able to shut down Tradehill or at least charge royalties if they were able to enforce their trademark. A very dangerous prospect.

If that's true, then had Mt. Gox not filed their Trademark, someone else could have and the problem would have been the same (except they could blackmail Mt. Gox as well, which would make things worse). So your issue is not with Mt. Gox.

Comment: TradeHill is dead. ...